# Can't compile due to missing files

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I get the following message:

> The project was not built due to "File not found: path/.DS_Store.".
>   Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent

This is a error message I've never seen before. I'm running Eclipse Indigo on a Mac OSX with Lion. As far as I understand the message my `.DS_Store` file is responsible for me not being able to compile, but how can that file mess with my code?!

Maybe what's interesting or not:

My file structure is as follows:

```
com.packagename
```

And it says `File not found: bin/com/.DS_Store`. It can't find the `.DS_Store` file in my binary output folder?

Comment: How is this file referenced? Search the code (grep or find or something) and check buildpath (rightclick on project -> properties -> buildpath)

Comment: the `.DS_Store` file is a hidden system file. Apple hid it for a reason, probably, so that explains it is messing with your code.

Comment: Yeah well. I haven't referenced it at all, not in the build path or anywhere in the code... And I know it's a hidden file. It's the most annoying file ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to refresh the project in the Project Navigator (F5 or Right click/Refresh).

These error messages are most likely caused by modifications in the file system outside Eclipse (e.g. external builder, or vcs tool is used), and Eclipse detects during the build that the file is changed.

Alternatively, if you are using a recent enough Eclipse, you could try two settings in the Preferences that might help in these cases as well: check *Refresh using native hooks* and *Refresh on access* in General/Workspace page in the Preferences dialog.

Comment: I already tried refreshing, but didn't help. I also just changed the settings in Eclipse and checked the things you said, also didn't help.

Comment: Hmm. I restarted Eclipse and now everything works. Not quite sure if your settings helped or if it was just an coincidence, but I'll accept this answer as correct.